# Access VBA code to print individual PDFs for each record - stops at 10th record

Tags: ms-access, vba

My question is regarding code I have to print out an Access report to PDF files. I need individual PDFs for each group, so that I can send each group their sales, and only their sales. The report prints out each item sold and the details of the sale. My code works, however after the 10th grouping it stops and gives me error code 3048: cannot open any more databases. I read on another thread that access has a limit of 2048 references, however my dataset is not really that huge. My code is as follows (I have labeled my report name REPORT and the group identifier GROUP, my QUERY pulls from 2 tables):

```
Private Sub Report_Click()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim MyFileName As String
    Dim mypath As String
    Dim temp As String


    mypath = "PATH\Access PDF Testing\"

    Set db = CurrentDb()

    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [GROUP] FROM [QUERY]", dbOpenSnapshot)

    Do While Not rs.EOF

        temp = rs("GROUP")
        MyFileName = rs("GROUP") & ".PDF"

        DoCmd.OpenReport "REPORT", acViewReport, , "[GROUP]='" & temp & "'"
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, mypath & MyFileName
        DoCmd.Close acReport, "REPORT"
        DoEvents

        rs.MoveNext
    Loop


    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

It will work, but after printing 10 groups to PDF, it fails. I tried running only groups without special characters in their names, I turned out forced page breaks, but nothing will get it past the 10th group record. Each group has roughly 10-20 rows within it. Is there any insight anyone can provide as to what I can do differently?

Comment: have you stepped through the code and looked at the values being sent to the OutPutTo? Also I know sometimes you have to push a MoveLast, and MoveFirst to a record set to make sure it is at the top of the data before you start your loop iterations. Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Alan, thanks for your answer. It looks like everything should be working for the OutPutTo statement: DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, mypath & MyFileName -- This is the portion that the debugger highlights, and it looks good when I step into the code and check the values. I added in the rs.MoveFirst just above the Do While Not loop, and it actually helped in that it gave me 3 more pdf files, but then gave me an error 3014 cannot open any more tables.

Comment: Which command is it that pops the error?  I am guessing the OpenReport?   One thing to try, if you are not already, point the report data source to a query that just pulls down all the fields from the table, but edit the query properties to be "snapshot" recordset type

Comment: For the tables error, ***DoCmd.OpenReport "POV Sales by Dealer", acViewReport, , "[DBA]='" & temp & "'"*** this is what pops the error. I have ***Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT distinct [GROUP] FROM [QUERY]", dbOpenSnapshot)*** (I just realized now that I misrepresented it in my above code as the report and not a query, I will change that), is there another portion here I should change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that "Each group has roughly 10-20 rows within it".  However your OpenRecordset doesn't have a `distinct` clause, meaning it pulls every single record out of REPORT.  Perhaps you are actually opening exporting each report 10-20 times and not just once?

Try:

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT distinct [GROUP] FROM [REPORT]", dbOpenSnapshot)
```

(If this works the way I think it will, you will be put back under that 2048 limit and it will run much faster. But it still doesn't explain to me why that limit is even an issue since you are closing each report right after you make it)

Comment: PowerUser, thank you so much! This helped immensely! It works great and it's MUCH faster. It did appear I was opening the report 10-20 times for each group, as now instead of flashing the print box several times, it does it once per page. I have 191 groups to pull, and I got to 169 and it gave me the error that it cannot open any more tables. Am I just reaching my limit considering I have so many reports to pull?

Comment: My best guess is that the code is not releasing the Report objects from memory even though you are closing them.  Try replacing your DoCmd methods with a Report object. There will be more code to maintain, but you'll have more control.  I'd do this myself if I could, but I don't have the time right now. Sorry.